# Require a JSON file based on a variable at run time

Tags: javascript, metro-bundler

I have about 10 JSON files now but can be changed as times goes by. Their content differs but structure is the same. Here is the method that processes a specific file:

```js
_process(id) {
  const source = require(`../../assets/${id}.json`)
}
```

The above fails at compilation because it is not found. I can't import the files at the top cos out of the files, may be 2-3 are needed, hence the imports would be unnecessary. But still happy to hearing a way forward. At most 4 files are needed by the user based on role.

Comment: What module bundler are you using?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki Metro

Comment: Maybe you could send request to the back-end and resolve json response there?

Comment: @MantasGiniūnas what do you mean backend? I have no back-end at all nor want to have one for this specific pure front-end requirement.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60562457/import-file-dynamically-by-variable-react-native) explains thing a bit. You have to explicitly require all mentioned files for later use.