# dynamically render svg icons in react

Tags: reactjs, svg, ecmascript-6

so I have around 40 svgs in my frontend in seperate files,
and I have an api route that gives me the name of the svg on request to I can import it, but I'm not quite sure how to dynamically import these svgs in react right now

I tried this but it means I can't change styles of svgs if I render them in img tag

```
export const renderIcon = ({ name, folder }) => {
  return <img src={`/${folder}/${name}.svg`} alt="" />;
};
```

is there a better way of doing this?

context:

basically name just returns the name of the svg and folder is only either "outline" or "filled", I was trying to find a way to return the svg from this file but i couldn't so i was trying the img instead.

Comment: please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60562457/import-file-dynamically-by-variable-react-native

Comment: Are you importing files bundled with your code or are you simply proving the source URL for an `img` tag? It seems you've the latter. You could preprocess and generate image source URLs and simply pass the `src` as a prop. Can you provide a bit more context? What is rendering `renderIcon` and what is `name` and `folder`?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry, just added more context on the question

Comment: Where are the SVG files located in relation to your app? Could you try creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for what you are trying to do?

Comment: they're in the public folder of the frontend ( nextjs ) so basically if the svg is in /public/home.svg i can just add <img src="/home.svg" /> and it would work fine, I'm just not sure how to return it like that because the name of it comes dynamically from an api so I can't just import it in the top of the file